# Compiler error linking objects for remote compiling in visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors

Currently I run a freenas jail so I can compile my c code, that uses some POSIX functions. The jail is fresh, all I did was enable SSH and 'pkg install gcc'. However I get the following error:

```
1>Starting remote build
1>Compiling sources:
1>main.c
1>cc1 : warning : command line option '-fthreadsafe-statics' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
1>cc1 : warning : command line option '-frtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
1>Linking objects
1>/usr/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd11.1/6.4.0/../../../libstdc++.so : error : undefined reference to `__cxa_thread_atexit_impl@FBSD_1.5'
1>collect2 : error : ld returned 1 exit status
1>Done building project "testingdesktop.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I don't have a clue what's going on, something is missing but I am not sure why.

Comment: Seeing the relevant bit of code and the command that you're running to compile it would help

Comment: I have no idea how visual studio runs compilation. The project setting is cross-platform development->Linux. If you know how I can find out what command it passes to the compiler I will look it up.

Comment: Oh the code is printf("Hello"); thats it.